# rails fields_for nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an CEvemt model which has an association to Schedule model, now I'm trying to implement a form with multiple schedule objects: an user can add more schedule fields if he clicks the "Add more" link.

My form code:

```
<% 3.times do |x| %>
  <%= render :partial => "schedule_field", :locals => {:event => @schedule} %>
<% end %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :schedule_fields_count, 2 %>
<%= link_to "Add more", "#", :id => "add_schedule_field" %>
```

partial:

```
<%= fields_for :event, event.schedules.build do |s| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-3.5 columns">
        <%= s.datetime_select :start %>      
    </div>
    <div class="small-3.5 columns">     
        <%= s.datetime_select :finish %>
    </div>
    <div class="small-5 columns">
      <%= s.text_field :description %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and for load more I use this view

```
$("#schedule_fields").
  append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'schedule_field', :locals => {:event => @event}) %>");

$("#schedule_fields_count").val("<%= @number %>");
```

The problem is that this code doesn't render what I want.. For example on form I have 3 schedule description fields which all have the same name `schedule[description]`, so the date is incorrect and I can't save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need following line in your model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :schedules
```

This line will define a setter `schedules_attributes=` which will be later used in your form. You might want to pass some extra options like `allow_destroy: true` or `reject_if: :all_blank`.

Following lines:

```
<% 3.times do |x| %>
  <%= render :partial => "schedule_field", :locals => {:event => @schedule} %>
<% end %>
```

with partial are incorrect. You need to call `field_for` only once, and it should be called on your current form builder object. Instead do:

```
<%= f.fields_for :schedules do |s| %>
  <%= render 'schedule_fields', f: s %>
  <%= link_to "Add more", "#", :id => "add_schedule_field" %>
<% end %>
```

`fields_for` will check whether object associated with `form_builder` implements `schedules_attributes=` setter (created by `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method) and will behave accordingly.
Note: you do not need to specify `partial:` in render - this is a default inside a view. I would rename your partial to `schedule_fields` to use it with cocoon, but I'll get to it later. Your partial should only contains fields without `fields_for` call:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-3.5 columns">
    <%= f.datetime_select :start %>      
  </div>
  <div class="small-3.5 columns">     
    <%= f.datetime_select :finish %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-5 columns">
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Building new objects should be placed in your controller, not in your view (as otherwise you won't be able to use the same partial for editing existing schedules). So in your controller do sth like:

```
(3 - @user.schedules.count).times { @user.schedules.build }
```

This will ensure you always have at least 3 schedules to display.

This should do it. As a lest step I would advise you to look at mentioned above `coccon` gem. It is quite powerful tool  for client side association creation and deletion. You can read about it here: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: this works if you have a fixed number of fields, in this case 3, in this case you cannot add another new field because you provide the partial the form object

Comment: You can add new fields with this approach. Fields_for will render all the partial for every associated object and form builder will handle those objects.

Comment: I mean you cannot add a new field via ajax, or I'm missing something?

Comment: You are not adding anything via AJAX, but pure Javascript - that's what cocoon gem is for. You simply write `<%= link_to_add_association 'Add more', f, :schedules %>`, where you are passing form builder to render all fields exactely as needed.